# exe error with cx_freeze

Tags: python, pyqt4, cx-freeze

Hey am relatively new to compiling python scripts to exe. Im using cx_freeze to compile my scripts and once its built i run the exe and it gives me this error. Have google around alot but not too sure. Error is:

```
Cannot import traceback module.
Exception: No module named re
Original Exception: No module named re
```

Not too sure how to go about fixing this. I read that possibly there is a clash between a module named re? in python? and a module named re in cx_freeze module?

My setup file looks like:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = []
includefiles = ['remindersText.pkl']
eggsacutibull = Executable(
    script = "podlancer.py",
    initScript = None,
    base = 'Win32GUI',
    targetName = "podlancer.exe",
    compress = True,
    copyDependentFiles = True,
    appendScriptToExe = False,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    icon = None
    )

setup(
        name = "Podlancer",
        version = "0.1",
        author = 'jono',
        description = "Podlancer UI script",
        options = {"build_exe": {"includes":includes, "include_files": includefiles}},
        executables = [eggsacutibull]
        )
```

Comment: This is a bug in cx_Freeze - it should be fixed in the next release, which hopefully is coming in the next week or so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change

```
includes = []
```

to

```
includes = ["re"]
```

That worked for me

Comment: legend. =) Thanks bro! would like to know what actually happened lol. I take it when compiling it needed to include that re module for watever reason...hence putting it in includes (makes sense,kinda gutted i didnt think of that!)...anyone know what the re module is for?

Answer (score 2):

cx_freeze will barf if the runtime working directory is not the directory that the executable is in.

Is re the first import you do? What happens when you do them in a different order?

Answer (score 0):

Meeting this same problem putting `re` in `includes` didn't work for me.  It produced a `cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError` when rebuilding the .py file.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'include_files': ['re']}

setup(  name = "Foreground Window Montior",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Query the foreground window.",
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("actWin_Query.py")])
```

If I put `re` in `packages` rather than in `include_files` it did not produce this compile error.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["re"]}

setup(  name = "Foreground Window Montior",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Query the foreground window.",
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("actWin_Query.py")])
```