# Import Module error when using cx_Freeze (PYTHON)

Tags: python, compilation, cx-freeze, xlsxwriter

I have spent the last 2 hours searching the web to find very little and nothing that helps.

Hoping someone here will be able to help me.

When using cx_Freeze to convert my .py file to a .exe files, I get an error stating no module named xlsxwriter can be found. 
When this module is removed from the packages list the program compiles with no problem.

My code:

```
import cx_Freeze

Executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("test.py")]


cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Sort PLL Bale Lists",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":['xlrd','xlsxwriter']}},

    executables = Executables

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding includes list to your code eg: `includes = [xlrd,xlsxwriter]`. Refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603287/exe-error-with-cx-freeze) for help. If the error persists try installing xlrdwriter with `pip install xlsxwriter`.

There is a chance that you have xlrd already installed and you have not installed xlsxwriter. This can be verified with pip freeze. `pip freeze` will provide a list of installed packages.

Comment: I am using xlsxwriter in the file I am trying to compile. It imports fine when importing there.

Comment: You may mark answer as solved if your issue is fixed that this post will help others.